# How to access docker app from virtual machine on host?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, port, putty

I installed docker on virtual machine and started container there. My container is now running and I want to see the app on my host machine.

docker container ls command returns

PORTS:
0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp

but I'm not sure how to work with this, and how to access the app on my host browser.

Comment: What is the vm's network setup?

Comment: If the setup is correct, go to 0.0.0.0:8080 in your browser

Comment: Since  0.0.0.0:8080 is not working, i should probably change setup, but not quite sure what to change and how?

Comment: `127.0.0.1:8080` not work? Did you really open `8080` in container?

Comment: If i understand you had installed docker on **VM** which is different to your **Host machine**, and you want to show website on you **host machine** not in you **VM machine**.  If yes try to use **PORT FORWARDING** on your VM Setup using bridged network

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

first you most sure that you could access to vm whit ping or telnet to your VMs IP.

if you don't have access read this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/227505/what-is-the-difference-between-nat-bridged-host-only-networking/227527)

if you have access your URL will be --->  http://yourVMip:8080

Comment: So my docker container has ip 172.xx.. , my VM has ip 188.xx.. and my computer has ip 128.xx.. . So container has connection with VM, VM has connection with my computer, but my computer doesn't have connection with docker container which is running web application I want to see in my computer's browser. What kind of connection do you suggest I should try to set up?

Comment: If in docker ps you see  0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp below PORT section means that your container serve 8080 and doesn't problem. I think your have connection problem between your OS and Vm. first sure that you don't have any firewall and rule in your VM. Check port 8080 in your VM machine by command: telnet 127.0.0.1 8080 if resolute was true you have connection issue between your own OS and VM